# Hyperledger problem downloading with go get using modules

Tags: go, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I'm using go modules inside my project, and when trying to run: `go get -u github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/shim` 
I'm prompted with a checksum error.

```
go: finding github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/shim latest
go: finding github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core latest
go: finding github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode latest
go: downloading github.com/hyperledger/fabric v1.4.4
verifying github.com/hyperledger/fabric@v1.4.4: checksum mismatch
        downloaded: h1:2m+tDXB5QWyZL1UTyYs3fxUhkgvKD88yVE6sIwYf1KM=
        sum.golang.org: h1:Joa6eO9HEGnzcuZF5RD+dZBPeYqxGF+ehYb7OSs3glY=

SECURITY ERROR
This download does NOT match the one reported by the checksum server.
The bits may have been replaced on the origin server, or an attacker may
have intercepted the download attempt.

For more information, see 'go help module-auth'.
```

I've tried to reset modcache but to no avail, the only thing I can think of is use another checksum server in order to verify the package.

My question is: how to download shim with go modules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shim is now located at github.com/hyperledger/fabric-chaincode-go/shim. You can `go get` it from there

Comment: Just had time to test it, the solution works. Still, fabric documentation needs to be updated.

Comment: Can you point me to where in the doc this is referenced so I can make sure we update it before our next release

Comment: building chaindocde section -> https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/chaincode4ade.html

Comment: You're looking at our release doc, it's a weird place, we have to keep up two doc paths in 1.4, one for 1.4.3 and the change that happened at 1.4.4. we did update this in the latest doc, https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/chaincode4ade.html

Comment: Gotcha, unfortunately while googling or exploring docs you might end up clicking old docs links.